# Convert xy Cartesian field in CSV file to shapefile with latitude and longitude field

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates, convert, csv

I am trying to convert the CSV file that I have for a shapefile.  The CSV file contains a Cartesian xy coordinate field that I wanted to convert to xy longitude and latitude field in the shapefile.  I have QGIS I succeeded in converting the CSV file to shapefile but the coordinate field is the same xy Cartesian. I am attaching the files I want to convert in the comment, two of them are point data and one is polygon data. All the files contain data for places in the UK.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find a link to attach the files.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  By asking how to do the same thing in either of two products you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad for focused Q&A.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.

Comment: Use the "Project" tool.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring in the data as you say in "cartesian" coordinates. Most likely your data is in British National Grid, so EPSG:27700. But you want to check this in the source data.

Once it is in QGIS, you need to reproject the data (convert to a different projection).

This can be done with *Vector> Data Management Tools> Reproject layer*.

And reproject to WGS:84, EPSG:4326. Which will transform the coordinates to Lat/Long.